# Finding sum: Is recursion necessary, and what would a recursive algorithm look like?

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

```
def numPens(n):
    """
    n is a non-negative integer

    Returns True if some non-negative integer combination of 5, 8 and 24 equals n
    Otherwise returns False.
    """
    if n < 5:
        return False
    N = n
    while N >= 0:
        if  N % 24 == 0 or N % 8 == 0 or N % 5 == 0: # if N / 24 is equal to 0 then we can buy N pens
            return True
        if N < 5:
            return False    # if N < 5 we cannot buy any pens

        if  N > 24:         # if N is greater than 24 , take away 24 and continue loop
            N -= 24
        elif N > 8:         # if N is greater than 8, take away 8 and continue loop
            N -= 8
        else:
            N -= 5          # else take away 5 and continue loop
```

I had to create  this function for a test, I am just wondering if the problem can be sorted recursively or what would be most efficient solution, I am new to programming so any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Technically, since you are modifying the value of N towards zero and re-evaluating each time a modification is made, it already is recursive.  You're simply not containing your evaluation in a function that calls itself.

Comment: ok thanks, I have always associate recursion with a call to the function as that is the only way I have seen so far, is there a simpler way of accomplishing what I had to do?

Comment: Yeah, it's helpful to remember too that ALL recursions are loops, whether explicitly written that way or not.

Comment: @ecline6 It's misleading to suggest that this is already recursive. Generally speaking, when a recursive algorithm is converted into an iterative one there will be an explicit stack variable to keep track of the recursive state. The OP's algorithm has no stack.

Comment: -1, I'm sorry. First of all, what you're doing here is not called "combination" but "[composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(number_theory))". Then, your question's title "python algorithm" is by far too generic. Same for your tags. Please correct and improve your question and I will be pleased to undo my downvote.

Comment: I did not put the combinations tag  and I have been programming for about five weeks so sorry if my title is not 'perfect'.

Comment: @JohnKugelman You're absolutely right!  And whenever we talk about recursion, we're usually dealing with a problem that requires storage of states.  However, stacks are not a requirement of recursion. Recursion simply is the repeating of an algorithm on its returned value.

Comment: I'd start by simplifying the question to finding if N is a non-negative integer combination of 5 and 8. Since 24 is 3*8 it's redundant to look for 24.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if  N % 24 == 0 or N % 8 == 0 or N % 5 == 0
```

If you get rid of the above modulus (`%`) checks then your algorithm is what's known as a [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). It subtracts the largest number it can each iteration. As you might have noticed, the greedy algorithm doesn't work. It gives the wrong answer for **15** = 5 + 5 + 5, for example.

```
 15 (-8) --> 7 (-5) --> 2 --> False
```

By adding in the modulus checks you've improved the greedy algorithm because it now correctly handles 15. But it still has holes: for instance, **26** = 8 + 8 + 5 + 5.

```
 26 (-24) --> 2 --> False
```

In order to correctly solve this problem you must abandon the greedy approach. It's not always sufficient to subtract the largest number possible. To answer your question, yes, a recursive solution is called for here.

```
def numPens(n):
    """
    n is a non-negative integer

    Returns True if some non-negative integer combination of 5, 8 and 24 equals n
    Otherwise returns False.
    """
    # Base case: Negative numbers are by definition false.
    if n < 0:
        return False

    # Base case: 0 is true. It is formed by a combination of zero addends,
    # and zero is a non-negative integer.
    if n == 0:
        return True

    # General case: Try subtracting *each* of the possible numbers, not just
    # the largest one. No matter what n-x will always be smaller than n so
    # eventually we'll reach one of the base cases (either a negative number or 0).
    for x in (24, 8, 5):
        if numPens(n - x):
            return True

    return False
```

This is the most straightforward way to solve the problem and will work reasonably well for smallish numbers. For large numbers it will be slow due to the way it evaluates the same numbers multiple times. An optimization left to the reader is to use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) to eliminate duplicate calculations.

Comment: Was just writing a comment to say that the Greedy Algorithm doesn't work here, using the example of 26, but you beat me to it. :)

Anyway, this shows a clean, easy to understand recursive solution, so +1. It might run into trouble with the maximum recursion depth in Python in the real world, but that probably doesn't matter here.

Comment: the algorithm is not complete, numPens(0) return True.

Comment: My code should have  elif N > 8: not if I tried to edit but couldn't. Thanks for the input, your solution looks a lot better than mine :)

Comment: would using if n < 5: return False and just using the for loop take care of negative ints and return False if n was equal to zero

Comment: @PadraicCunningham According to your spec, 0 should return True. Read it carefully. That's why I coded it the way I did.

Comment: I am unclear on why 0 should return true, can you explain?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Notice the very careful wording of "non-negative integer" in the spec. It doesn't say "positive", it says "non-negative". Non-negative includes zero. You can add zero 5's, zero 8's, and zero 24's to reach a total of 0. There *is* a way to add together 5's, 8's, and 24's to reach 0. You add together zero of them!

Comment: I understand your reasoning, this was the problem description: Write a function, called numPens that takes one argument, n, and returns True if it is possible to buy a combination of 5, 8 and 24 pack units such that the total number of pens equals exactly n, and otherwise returns False.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sure. If you buy zero packs then the total number of pens will equal 0. The answer is yes, n=0 is possible.

Answer (score 3):

There are more efficient (O(1)) algorithms.

For instance, you can add

```
if n > 40: 
    return True
```

as one of your base cases!

You can make it even more efficient, by maintaining a lookup table for the rest of the values (n < 40).

The reason you can do this is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_.3D_2

Comment: so simple but so effective, I think I need to brush up on my maths! :)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it's a recursive problem, below is maybe the simplest code:

```
def numPens(n):
    if n < 5:
        return False
    elif n==5 or n==8 or n==24:
        return True
    else:
        return numPens(n-5) or numPens(n-8) or numPens(n-24)
```

if you need to be more efficient and robust, you can improve by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`n=5a+8b+24c <=> n=5a+8(b+3c)`,
hence you could have a function :

```
def numPens(n):
    if n < 5:
        return False
    if n % 8 == 0 or n % 5 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return numPens(n-8) or numPens(n-5)
```

Comment: I would never have though of that thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
def numPens(n):
    global cantidad
    cantidad = cantidad + 1
    if n < 5:
        return False
    elif n%5==0 or n%8==0 or n%24==0:
        return True
    else:
        return numPens(n-5) or numPens(n-8) or numPens(n-24)
```

Answer (score 0):

An informal definition of recursion given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive defines recursion as: "Recursion is the process a procedure goes through when one of the steps of the procedure involves invoking the procedure itself." On the other hand iteration is defined as: "Iteration means the act of repeating a process with the aim of approaching a desired goal, target or result. Each repetition of the process is also called an "iteration," and the results of one iteration are used as the starting point for the next iteration." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itteration

As you can see the two processes are very similar. Any loop that is not infinite will be iterative, and could be written in a recursive manner, and any recursive call could be written as an iterative loop. However in many cases one method or the other is much easier to implement.